# Shorthand way to check for function parameters

Tags: javascript, syntax

In my code, I have a function that creates a new map given a few parameters. I want to make it so that if no parameters are passed, some default values will be used.

Why won't this work:

```
 function create(a,b,c) {
   return new Map(a,b,c || 10,1,10); // create new map using a b c as parameters
   // or 10, 1, 10 if none entered.
}

 create();
```

Assume that there is a constructor function 'Map' that would accept and process these parameters.

What can i do besides having an if/else type check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortest way i know under some limitations is to use

```
<var> = <var> || <defaultvalue>;
```

So

```
Return new Map((a = a || 10), (b = b || 1), (c = c || 10));
```

However this way its hardly readable and you might want to consider moving the assignments before the constructor.

The limitation however is that all falsy values lead to the default being assigned which might be a problem for some numeric values.

Comment: Remarks: the syntax above is a more general version for > val = val === 'undefined' ? Defaultvalue : value;

Comment: This is probably what I was going for, but you're right it's not really all that readable. 
I have a check in place that says if !a, then a = 10, etc.
Thanks for your help then.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
function create(a, b, c) {
     a = typeof a !== 'undefined' ? a : 10;
     b = typeof b !== 'undefined' ? b : 1;
     c = typeof c !== 'undefined' ? c : 10;
     return new Map(a, b, c);
}
```

Javascript does not offer default function value parametization.

Comment: Thank you, this is similar to what I had in place already. Good to know there are possibly better ways to do it, though. Also, too bad JavaScript doesn't have something like that.